# How to access the crm files

Tags: drupal-views

We would like to change the minor changes in the content page and webform design, dont know how to access the file. How to get the FTP files from my site need to add custom css file. Any help please.

Comment: it would help if you gave specific examples of what you want to customise and what sort of a change you need to make - then you will get much clearer answers

Answer (score 3):

I would recomment reading up on how to customize CiviCRM here: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/ and here: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/customize/extensions/

That should answer your question and also allow you to do the customizations in a recommended and structured way.

If you would like a more specific answer it will help us all ot help you if you tell us a little more about what you want to change for what reason, what version of CiviCRM you are using and what CMS.

Comment: Thanks for your help. i am drupal site would like to customize the menu link navset style, tried with custom css url it reflects only for civi component webform.

Comment: i went through the document in that Directories-> Custom PHP Directory is to put the customized page, like that i want to customize style sheet also would like to know how to access the file which means download or upload existing files in cyberduck etc.

Comment: Navigation menu in the home page